# Parallax & Slider materialize.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css, materialize

Estoy desarrollando en front-end y busco la manera de poder hacer un slider con parallax con el framework de materialize pero no he podido, el efecto es poder hacer una slide de imagenes pero usando igualmente un parallax. Si alguien a usado este framework sabra de que hablo.

**CODIGO HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
      <ul class="parallax slides ">
        <li>
          <div class="parallax"><img src="B3.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 2"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="parallax"><img class="responsive-img" src="background1.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 2"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**CODIGO JS**

```
(function($){
  $(function(){

    $('.slider').slider();
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    $('.parallax').parallax();


  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

Agradezco de antemano a quien pueda colaborarme.

Comment: servirá esto? http://materializecss.com/carousel.html

Comment: @jolsalazar http://materializecss.com/parallax-demo.html#!, este es un ejemplo de una view que usa parallax pero lo que quiero esque esa imagen principal haga un slide sin perder su estilo.